# Find files that are heavily used in the system

Tags: files, performance

`atopsar -d 30` - shows that one of hard drive (sda) in the system is heavily used.

Is there a way to know which files are heavily used on HDD?

Comment: I know that mysql does this load as HDD is dedicated to mysql server. And when I stop mysqld load became 0%. But I do not understand the reason of such big HDD load. I need to know exact files. Can it be that mysql InnoDB log files (ib_logfile) are fragmented? And therefore `atopsar` show such big load (50%-70%). What can be done in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out the most heavily used files in the system please use: `sudo pt-ioprofile -cell sizes`
Example of output:

```
     total      pread       read     pwrite      fsync      lseek filename
  10862592          0          0   10862592          0          0 /var/mysqldata/mysql/ibdata1
    827392          0          0     827392          0          0 /var/mysqllog/mysql/ib_logfile0
... (other trivial I/O records truncated)
```

Got it from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21209/innodb-high-disk-write-i-o-on-ibdata1-file-and-ib-logfile0

Please be aware that by default Percona toolkit attaches only to mysqld. And to find out most heavily used file you have to run it to all processes that might create such load. In my case I was definitely sure that it's mysql server, so it's enough for me.

Please read http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-ioprofile.html before you use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lsof [(man lsof)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof). The following will return a list of all files that are open for writing:

```
lsof | grep -e "[[:digit:]]\+w"
```

Comment: It's strange, I thought that this command will give me all files that mysqld did open. But instead I have only *.log files that are open by mysqld, no others. And those log files are located at different HDD.
I do not think that list of open files for writing can sort things out.